# Circle and Player not visible despite being drawn

Tags: lua, drawing, love2d

Player nor circle is appearing.
The player and circle are being drawn but not now showing up on the screen.
When the player presses a key the player moves that way, the player stops on the grid and cant move outside the grid.

Full Code

```
-- Initialize the square position and speed
local square = {
    x = 100,
    y = 100,
    gridSize = 25, -- Adjust the size of each grid cell
    targetX = 100, -- Target position for animation
    targetY = 100,
    animationSpeed = 200, -- Adjust animation speed as needed
    isMoving = false -- Flag to check if animation is active
}

function love.load()
    -- Set the window dimensions
    love.window.setMode(252, 252)
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    -- Move the square based on keyboard input
    if not square.isMoving then -- Only move if animation is not active
        local newX, newY = square.x, square.y

        if key == "up" then
            newY = square.y - square.gridSize
        elseif key == "down" then
            newY = square.y + square.gridSize
        elseif key == "left" then
            newX = square.x - square.gridSize
        elseif key == "right" then
            newX = square.x + square.gridSize
        end

        -- Check if the new position is within the grid boundaries
        if newX >= 0 and newX <= 225 and
           newY >= 0 and newY <= 225 then
            square.targetX = newX
            square.targetY = newY
            square.isMoving = true -- Start animation
        end
    end
end

function love.update(dt)
    if square.isMoving then
        -- Interpolate the square's position towards the target position
        local dx = square.targetX - square.x
        local dy = square.targetY - square.y
        local distance = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

        if distance > 1 then
            local step = square.animationSpeed * dt
            square.x = square.x + (dx / distance) * step
            square.y = square.y + (dy / distance) * step
        else
            -- Animation complete, snap to the target position
            square.x = square.targetX
            square.y = square.targetY
            square.isMoving = false -- Animation finished
        end
  end
end

function love.draw()
    -- Draw the transparent white circles
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5) -- Set color to white with transparency (alpha = 0.5)
    for x = square.gridSize / 2, 225 - square.gridSize / 2, square.gridSize do
        for y = square.gridSize / 2, 225 - square.gridSize / 2, square.gridSize do
            love.graphics.circle("fill", x, y, square.gridSize / 4) -- Draw a circle at the center of each grid box
        end
    end

    -- Draw the square (player)
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1) -- Set color to opaque white
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", square.x, square.y, square.gridSize, square.gridSize)
end
```

The potintal issue area

```
function love.draw()
    -- Draw the transparent white circles
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5) -- Set color to white with transparency (alpha = 0.5)
    for x = square.gridSize / 2, 225 - square.gridSize / 2, square.gridSize do
        for y = square.gridSize / 2, 225 - square.gridSize / 2, square.gridSize do
            love.graphics.circle("fill", x, y, square.gridSize / 4) -- Draw a circle at the center of each grid box
        end
    end

    -- Draw the square (player)
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1) -- Set color to opaque white
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill", square.x, square.y, square.gridSize, square.gridSize)
end
```

Whats expected: A player is drawn and on keypress moves that way, the circle appears to show where the player can move.

Whats gotten: A fully blank screen.

Comment: I can see gray circles and a white square that can move on the circles, though there are some minor issues, there are things on the screen.

Comment: So wait, you're able to see the circles? So its most likely an issue on my end?

Comment: There are several questions: Which version of love and OS are you using? Can you see the default screen of love? Can you see the player if you draw the player only?

Comment: Your main.lua is a working Example. Maybe your Screen keeps black because you have to wait the twitching movement has to stop? Each time the Position change and the player is twitching it cant be moved. Thats because of ```math.sqrt()``` returns Floatingpoint Numbers. Correct and try it to: ```local distance = math.floor(math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy))``` in ```love.update()```

Comment: Remember that the color model changed in version 11.0 (from 255 to 1.0). If you use an older version, an alpha of 0.5 would be basically invisible.